# ClickHouse failed with the error "DirectoryMonitor: Checksum of extra info doesn't match: corrupted data"

Tags: clickhouse

My binary files came with curves inside the data (my fault). ClickHouse could not insert it into the table and stopped processing other data. I just opened the binary file for editing and fixed the wrong field. After that, ClickHouse took the file and gave an error about an invalid checksum.

```sh
default.affiliate_program.DirectoryMonitor: Code: 40, e.displayText() = 
DB::Exception: Checksum of extra info doesn't match: corrupted data. Reference: cb322c17e14d6816abfcdc16842e7bdd. Actual: f4afe41e77b9a92bfa4048648a3aebbb.,
```

after, ClickHouse transferred the file to the broken folder and went on.
Is it possible to change checksum may be or anything else for processed my files which I rewrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just extend the original question and answer by @Denny Crane.

---

I got a similar error because of the wrong configuration [default-profile](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings-profiles/) - it was marked as [readonly](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/permissions-for-queries/#settings_readonly). As result subsequent data insertion to a distributed table lead to error like this:

```sh
database.table.DirectoryMonitor: Code: 164, e.displayText() = 
DB::Exception: Received from **:9000. 
DB::Exception: default: Cannot execute query in readonly mode. Stack trace:

0. Poco::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0x10519be0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0x8f5072d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
..
```

When inserting to the distributed table:

> .. the data block is just written to the
> local file system. .. You should check whether data is sent
> successfully by checking the list of files (data waiting to be sent)
> in the table directory: /var/lib/clickhouse/data/database/table/."

(see for details [Distributed Table Engine](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed/))

Let's look inside the */var/lib/clickhouse/data/database/table/*-folder and check 'hanging' bin-file to find the reason for the issue:

```sh
sudo vim /var/lib/clickhouse/data/database/table/default@../3757.bin
```

At the top of bin-file reside original sql-query and query settings. In my case the *readonly* set to 1 (see last row) is source of problem that does not allow execute insert (format bin-file can be changed in future and output will be different):

```sh
Îµû×^L<88>^H¡©^Cõ^FINSERT INTO database.table({column_list}) VALUES^V
use_uncompressed_cache^@^A0^N
load_balancing^@^F
random^Q
force_primary_key^@^A1^K
log_queries^@^A1^H
readonly^@^A1^P
..
```

---

To fix it need to:

1. fix the root reason (in my case need to correctly define the *default*-profile) and check that test inserts work correctly
2. on each node of cluster do

- move (not copy) 'hanging' bin-file(s) from `/var/lib/clickhouse/data/database/table/default@../` to `/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/`
- open file(s) from CH and re-insert

```sql
# check data availability
SELECT count()
FROM file('*.bin', 'Distributed')

# re-insert data
INSERT INTO database.table
SELECT *
FROM file('*.bin', 'Distributed')
# FROM file('3757.bin', 'Distributed')
```

- remove processed 'hanging' files from origin folder `/var/lib/clickhouse/user_files/`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/16005

It's impossible to change .bin file for Distributed table. It has built-in checksum so one need to recalculate it but that is cumbersome.

But there another way. Not corrupted .bin file can selected and inserted manually `select * from file('/path/to/file.bin', 'Distributed')`

more details: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/9653